# Can I set my computer to say ' Shut down ' when I shut it down rather than show GNOME Lines?

Tags: shutdown, gnome-terminal

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and the first time I shut it down it started showing GNOME lines. I didn't change any settings before and it goes on for a reasonable amount of time. I don't want to use terminal because I'm new to Ubuntu, Linux and GNOME! So can anyone give me a way to get Ubuntu to say Shutting Down rather then these lines?